# How do I import ActivityScenario?

Tags: android, androidx, androidx-test

I am attempting to follow the Android [`ActivityScenario` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) to write Robolectric-based tests. Adding `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.core:app:1.2.0"` to my `build.gradle` allows me to add `import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;` to my test class and use the `ActivityScenario` class. Despite this, gradle is reporting `Failed to resolve: androidx.test.core:app:1.2.0` which means I can't run the tests.

I have tried cleaning the build, re-running the gradle sync, invalidating caches and restarting. I have also tried importing other packages from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test, none of which result in  `ActivityScenario` being found. In particular, I would expect `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.2.0"` to work but it does not.

Versions:

- Android Studio 3.5
- Robolectric 4.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that because I am trying to write Robolectric tests which are not instrumented, I need to use `testImplementation` rather than `androidTestImplementation`.

Adding `testImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.2.0"` to my `build.gradle` works as expected.

How very strange that `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.core:app:1.2.0"` somehow tricked Android Studio into resolving the class.